# The fundamental group of the space $Y=S^3-(p^{-1}(\alpha_1)\cup ... \cup p^{-1}(\alpha_n))$, where $p :S^3 \to \Bbb CP^1$ is the quotient map

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

Consider $S^3$ as a subspace of $\Bbb C^2$, let $q : \Bbb C^2 \to \Bbb CP^1$ be the canonical quotient map, and let $p=q|_{S^3}$. (I heard that $p$ is a Hopf fibration, but I don't know what it is.) It is easy to see that $p^{-1}(\alpha)$ is homeomorphic to $S^1$, for each $\alpha \in \Bbb CP^1$.

Now, take finitely many points $\alpha_1, ..., \alpha_n \in \Bbb CP^1$, and conisder the subspace $Y=S^3-(p^{-1}(\alpha_1)\cup ... \cup p^{-1}(\alpha_n))$ of $S^3$. I want to compute $\pi_1(Y).$

1. Is $Y$ path-connected? This is not obvious to me.
2. How do I have to compute $\pi_1(Y)$? I only know some basic theory of fundamental groups such as van Kampen theorem and covering spaces, so I need an elementary approach. Any hints?

Comment: Hint: Show that your space is homotopy equivalent to the product of $S^1$ and the wedge of $n-1$ circles. Then use the product formula for the fundamental group of the product of spaces. And yes, your map $p$ is the Hopf fibration.

Comment: @Kohan Then for $n>2$ circles, is the fundamental group of complement of the $  n$ circles is nonabelian? What I expected was $\Bbb Z^n$

Comment: Yes, it is nonabelian.

Comment: @Moishe Kohan Do you have any hints? I am having a hard time imagining the deformation retraction..

Comment: First prove that n times punctured 2-sphere deformation retracts to a wedge of circles. Then take preimage of this wedge under your map $p$.

Comment: @Moishe Kohan By regarding the codomain of $p$ $S^2$? Thanks I'll try

Comment: @MoisheKohan To follow your proof, I think I should show that $p^{-1}(S^2-\{\alpha_1, ..., \alpha_n \})$ is homeomorphic to $S^3-\{n$ points$\}$, but I think this is not true. Am I  wrong?

Comment: Of course, that would be utterly false. Instead show that the preimage of the wedge of circles is the product of this wedge with another circle.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Intuitively I can see it, but how do I have to prove it?

Comment: As I said, start by proving the existence of a deformation retraction for n times punctured 2-sphere. Can you do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is not a fully rigorous proof, but being elementary it might help you.

Suppose at first $\,n=1$.

Seeing $S^3$ as embedded in $\mathbb{C}^2$, you can verify that the following map

$\begin{align}
 f:\,&S^1 \times\mathring{D^2}\rightarrow S^3\setminus p^{-1}(x_1)\\
&(e^{i\theta}, re^{i\phi})\mapsto\:(\sqrt{1-r^2}e^{i\theta}, re^{i(\phi+\theta)})
\end{align}$

is a homeomorphism. Notice that $re^{i\phi}$ is the polar form for the elements in $\mathring{D^2}$, the open unit disc. Also observe that to construct this specific map I put $x_1=[0:1]\in \mathbb{C}P^1$, but there is no loss of generality since you can rotate $S^3$ in the first place.

Next, how can we make additional ring-shaped holes in $S^3$? Just puncture in $\mathring{D^2}$!

Specifically, choose $n-1$ distinct points $r_2e^{i\phi_2},\ldots, r_{n}e^{i\phi_{n}}$ in $\mathring{D^2}$ and restrict $f$ to $S^1\times\bigl(\mathring{D^2}\setminus\{r_2e^{i\phi_2},\ldots, r_{n}e^{i\phi_{n}}\}\bigr)$. Then there correspond $n-1$ distinct points $x_2,\ldots,x_n$ in $\mathbb{C}P^1$ in the same way as $x_1$ correspond to the boundary of $\mathring{D^2}$ in $\mathbb{C}$.

Now you must see how to compute the desired fundamental group, since each component of the space

$S^1\times\bigl(\mathring{D^2}\setminus\{r_2e^{i\phi_2},\ldots, r_{n}e^{i\phi_{n}}\}\bigr)$

has a familiar homotopy type.

Comment: Thanks I think that I can make this rigorously by writing down an explicit homeomorphism from $\Bbb CP^1 -\{x_1 \}$ to the open disk.

Comment: To obtain complete rigor, we should actually show that the fundamental group in question does not depend on the choice of $\{x_1, \ldots ,x_n\}$. Here I give you an intuitive explanation. Regarding van Kampen, your space can be 'flattened' into $\mathbb{R}^3-\text{circles}$ by a stereographic projection. But the fundamental group of this space depends on how the circles are linked. If you verify that each pair of circles are linked once regardless of the choice of $\{x_1,\ldots, x_n\}$, you're done; we can choose the points as we please.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no idea how to prove these lines rigorously, but consider the following; WLOG fix one circle in $S^3$ as simple as possible. Construct a 'disc' which has the circle as a boundary. Then verify that any other circle must intersect the disc once and only once. It suggests that every pair of circles are linked once(when projected onto $\mathbb{R}^3$).

Answer (score 1):

**A broad but not complete hint**

Once you realize that the map $p$ is $(z_1, z_2) \mapsto z_1/z_2$, it gets a little easier. It's clear that $p^{-1}(\alpha)$, for any $\alpha$ is just a curve on $S^3$.

In particular, if you think of $S^3$ as being $\Bbb R^3$ with an extra point at infinity, you can pick your $\alpha$s so that the point at infinity is not in the preimage of any of them, so what you've got is a bunch of curves in 3-space.

What do they look like? Well, let's that the case where the ratio is $0$ (i.e., $\alpha = 1$). Then we're looking at points $(z_1, z_2) \in S^3$ where $z_1 = 0$, i.e., we're looking at points $(0 + 0i, c + di)$ where $c^2 + d^2 = 1$. In $\Bbb R^3$, that looks just like a nice round circle.

It turns out that if you change $\alpha$ away from $0$ a tiny it, say, to $0.1$, you can again solve the equations, and you find that the preimage is more or less *another* circle...but it's linked with the first one. In fact any two preimages are linked exactly once.

Now the problem itself suggest that the choice of the $\alpha_i$s doesn't matter much, so you might as well pick them to suit yourself, and if you do (e.g., if you pick them to lie equally spaced around a unit circle in $\Bbb C$), the preimages will all lie on a single torus in $\Bbb R^3$. In fact, each one will be a $(1,1)$ torus knot: as you walk around the torus in one direction, the curve will "walk" around it once in the other direction as well. That's a little vague. Instead, suppose you regard the torus as a square with its edges identified pairwise as usual. The the preimages of the $\alpha_i$ will each be a 45-degree diagonal line in the square, equally spaced.

Proving all this requires writing down a bunch of formulas for things like stereographic projection from the sphere to 3-space, etc., and is kind of a pain in the neck.

But now at least I've got you started: the thing you want to compute is the fundamental group of 3-space with $n$ $(1,1)$-torus-knots removed.

Here: I found a link to a nice picture of a bunch of $(1,1)$ torus knots all on the same torus: https://collegemathteaching.files.wordpress.com/2015/07/torusknot.jpg

So you want to compute the fundamental group of $\Bbb R^3$ minus $n$ of those colored curves. (I'd suggest starting with $n = 1$ and $n = 2$, of course.)